# Farpoint spreadsheet - disable cell right click menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu, farpoint

I'm using Farpoint Spreadsheet for WinForms with C#. 
How can I disable the "context menu" displayed when right-clicking over a cell that is being edited?

Answer (score 1):

set AutoClipboard property of fpspread component to false